# Comparing Glassfish Connection Pool With Other Connection Pools

Tags: glassfish-3, connection-pooling, bonecp

Has anyone done any benchmarking comparing the glassfish connection pool with other fast jdbc connection pools like BoneCP or Tomcat 7 jdbc pool?

I am exploring out ways to create the glassfish connection pool programmatically (since the configuration details are determined at runtime) and I have read that it should be possible to do that through AMX or REST API.

The intent of this question is to get a first opinion on what are the pros and cons of using the glassfish connection pools over others? For e.g. We currently use Oracle's universal connection pool which has lock contention issues when the no. of requests to the pool increases. Are there any open well known issues with glassfish connection pool?

Thank you.

P.S - The glassfish version I use is 3.1.1.

Comment: I have similar question. I want to know which connection pool is faster and allows maximum connections Glassfish 3 or Tomcat 7?

Comment: If by faster you mean less lock contention then tomcat7 and bonecp are both faster when compared to Oracle's UCP connection pool. I didn't understand your question on what do you mean by "a pool allowing maximum connections"? Every pool provides an configuration option to set the max pool size.

Comment: Thanks for information. By max pool size I mean, what can be the max pool size without compromising the performance or speed in both.